# TextFileColumnDataTypes doesnt read my date as a text

Tags: excel, vba, string, csv, text

I use the following code to read my csv in VBA:

```
Sub OpenCSVFile(filePath As String, ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=.Range("A1"))
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat)
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ";"
            .Refresh
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

When I call the sub, the resulting worksheet does not read my dates in the csv as texts and changes their formatting to my local setting which is not what I want. I want all the columns to be read as text and they should be strings on that worksheet.

The values are not strings as they dont have a "'" in their cell. I also tried to change to the numberformat of the worksheet to "@" before I load the csv but that also does not give me the correct result. Please help.